# What is the := operator called in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, syntax, terminology, colon-equals

In VB.NET, you can invoke methods (or add attributes) with optional parameters like so:

```
DoSomething(FirstName:="Bob", LastName:="Smith")

...

<MyAttribute(SomeParam:=400)>
Public MyClass
    ...
```

I was trying to find out the *name* of the **`:=`** operator, so I looked within MSDN's [VB.NET 2010's Operators section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f15ea9k8.aspx) and couldn't find it listed.  Maybe it's not actually an *operator*, but instead something else?

I keep calling it the "*colon equals operator*" or the "*parameter assignment notation*" when talking to co-workers, but it would be nice to know what it is technically called.  For example, I would call the `<<` operator the "*left bit-shift operator*" and the `<=` operator the "*greater-than-or-equal comparison operator*." So then, **what should `:=` be called**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not an operator - it's just the syntax for [named arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51wfzyw0.aspx).

Comment: Hmm. I like your link better.

Answer (score 2):

Those are Named Arguments.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx